# Is this series for Pi correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, solution-verification

[image: diagram shows a bisected equilateral triangle of side length = radius]

The idea was to use an infinite series of triangles. The red then green then the... to get the area of this sector then the area of the circle is 16 times this. If it is a unit circle than area should equal Pi.

Here is the series I got using Pythagorean’s theorem , is it correct?

$$\begin{align}
A&=3r^{2} + 12\sum_{ n=0}^{\infty}2^{n-1}x_{n}\left(1-\sqrt{r^{2}-\frac{x{_{n}}^{2}}{4}}\right),\\ x_{0}&=r\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}
,\\x_{n+1}&=\sqrt{2r^{2}-2r\sqrt{r^{2}-\frac{x{_{n}}^{2}}{4}}}
\end{align}$$

So-for-a-unit-circle

$$\begin{align}
\pi&=3 + 12\sum_{ n=0}^{\infty}2^{n-1}x_{n}\left(1-\sqrt{1-\frac{x{_{n}}^{2}}{4}}\right),\\ x_{0}&=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}
,\\x_{n+1}&=\sqrt{2-2\sqrt{1-\frac{x{_{n}}^{2}}{4}}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Looks like something we did in school

Comment: Looks like [Viete's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula), except you are starting with a triangle instead of a square.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your posts using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format the math.

Comment: @saulspatz Done.

Comment: Archimedes did it first!

Comment: @herb steinberg: That's right.

Comment: "There was more imagination in Arquimedes' head than in Homer's" (Voltaire)

Comment: This is called the Method of Exhaustion, and as noted, it is thousands of years old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numerical calculation suggests that you have made an error (or that I have, of course.)

```
from math import sqrt, pi

xs = [sqrt(2-sqrt(3))]

def f(x):
    return sqrt(2-2*sqrt(1-x*x/4))

def a(x):
    return 1 - sqrt(1-x*x/4)

for _ in range(50):
    xs.append(f(xs[-1]))

answer = 3+sum(2**(n-1)*xs[n]*a(xs[n]) for n in range(50))

print("answer=", answer)
print((pi-3)/(answer-3))
```

produces the output

```
answer= 3.0117993877991496
11.999999999999849
```

Have you dropped a factor of $12$ before the sum, perhaps?

Comment: Yes it seems that is the case

Comment: Fixed it thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Note that, in
$x_{n+1}
=\sqrt{2-2\sqrt{1-\frac{x{_{n}}^{2}}{4}}}
$
if
$x_n = 2\sin(t)
$
then

$\begin{array}\\
x_{n+1}
&=\sqrt{2-2\sqrt{1-\frac{x{_{n}}^{2}}{4}}}\\
&=\sqrt{2-2\sqrt{1-\sin^2(t)}}\\
&=\sqrt{2-2\cos(t)}\\
&=2\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos(t)}{2}}\\
&=2\sin(\dfrac{t}{2})\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what do you mean I should notethis?

Comment: Just that your iteration divides the angle by 2, so it goes from an n-gon to a 2n-gon.

Comment: Ah yes thank you